# How do I upload images to github?

Tags: git, github

How can I upload images to my github through the browser?

I have an existing repo and I am wondering how can I upload an image into that repository.

Comment: why ..? you can't do that in command line ?

Answer (score 2):

Per this post, https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads, github no longer supports the feature you want.

Answer (score 0):

It not a good practice to upload images since they are binary files.

Take a look on solutions to binary files like: [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/)